# How do I add new column that adds and sums counts from existing column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have this python code:

```
counting_bach_new = counting_bach.groupby(['User Name', 'time_diff', 'Logon Time']).size()
print("\ncounting_bach_new")
print(counting_bach_new)
```

...getting this neat result:

```
counting_bach_new
User Name  time_diff            Logon Time
122770     -132 days +21:38:00  1             1
           -122 days +00:41:00  1             1
123526     -30 days +12:04:00   1             1
           -29 days +16:39:00   1             1
           -27 days +18:16:00   1             1
                                             ..
201685     -131 days +21:21:00  1             1
202047     -106 days +10:14:00  1             1
202076     -132 days +10:22:00  1             1
           -132 days +14:46:00  1             1
           -131 days +21:21:00  1             1
```

So how do I add new column that adds and sums counts from existing column? The rightmost column with 1's should be disregarded, while I--on the other hand--would like to add a new column, summing up counts of 'time diff's per 'User Name', i.e. the result in the new col should sum # of observations listed per user. Either summing up # of time_diffs or Logon Time's. For User Name 122770 the new col should sum up to 2, for 123526 it should sum up to 3, and so on....

I tried several attempts, including (but not working)...

```
counting_bach_new.groupby('User Name').agg(MySum=('Logon Time', 'sum'), MyCount=('Logon Time', 'count'))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you, for your kind support. Christmas Greetings from @Hubsandspokes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (counting_bach_new.to_frame('count')
                       .join((counting_bach_new.reset_index()
                                .groupby('User Name')
                                .agg(MySum=('Logon Time', 'sum'),
                                     MyCount=('Logon Time', 'count'))), on='User Name'))
print (df)
                                          count  MySum  MyCount
User Name time_diff           Logon Time                       
122770    -132 days +21:38:00 1               1      2        2
          -122 days +00:41:00 1               1      2        2
123526    -30 days +12:04:00  1               1      3        3
          -29 days +16:39:00  1               1      3        3
          -27 days +18:16:00  1               1      3        3
201685    -131 days +21:21:00 1               1      1        1
202047    -106 days +10:14:00 1               1      1        1
202076    -132 days +10:22:00 1               1      3        3
          -132 days +14:46:00 1               1      3        3
          -131 days +21:21:00 1               1      3        3
```

Comment: This works, but it needs to be represented as a new col with the 'counting_bach_new' subset of data. How can that be integrated, while still maintaining your fine suggestion? - Right now MySum and MyCount are appearing in a separate df, while they should appear to--e.g.--the right of the 'Logon Time' or 'time_diff' columns, or just somewhere in the 'counting_bach_new' df. Thx

Comment: Once again, thx - you did magic...:o) Answer accepted

Comment: Slowly moving ahead, I run into this issue, subtracting timedeltas and place difference per user name in a new column. May I ask you to look into my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240705/how-can-i-subtract-timedeltas-listed-in-same-column

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the request correctly, try:

```
counting_bach_new.reset_index().groupby(['User Name'])['Logon Time'].count()
```

If you need to save starting number of columns, try:

```
counting_bach_new.reset_index().groupby(['User Name'])['Logon Time'].transform('count')
```

Comment: Close, but not quite want I am really looking for....new col should place the sum of counts either per time_diff or Logon Time....I want it to say User Name: 122770 time_diff: 2 observations, Logon Time 1 1...new col: 2 (summing up either time_diff or Logon Time observations)...

Comment: maybe, you can fix this, too...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240705/how-can-i-subtract-timedeltas-listed-in-same-column